# How to know whether writing to stream would result in java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: java, android, io, outputstream

I know there are a number of posts here on the `java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)` exception, but non of them seems to answer my particular question:

Suppose my activity is called with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and I got a `Uri` via                 `Uri uri = intent.getData()` that starts with `content://` from which I read some data (for example a pdf file). Now I want to find out whether I can also write to that `Uri` to decide whether a "save" button should be shown to the user, or just a "save as" button.

Suppose further that I can successfully open first a `ParcelFileDescriptor` and finally a `FileOutputStream` as in

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
```

such that `fileOutputStream != null`.

Depending on the `Uri` it can now happen that if I try to write to `fileOutputStream` I get the exception:

```
Exception=java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
```

I would like to know in advance whether this will happen without actually touching/changing the file. One would think that it should be possible to find out whether I can write to a given `Uri` or not before trying.

How can I achieve that?

Additional observations:

I suppose that the above happens when I don't have permission to write to that particular file/uri, but then why does Android let me open a `FileOutputStream` in the first place?

For testing I use attachments in emails received with Kaiten mail on an ICS device. If I my app opens after I click on "save" in Kaiten mail `uri` matches `content://media/external/file/[0-9]*` and everything works, if I however clicked on "open" `uri` matches `content://com.kaitenmail.attachmentprovider/[-0-9a-f]*/[0-9]*/VIEW` and I run into the above error.

Comment: what about `public static StructStat android.system.Os#fstat(FileDescriptor fd)` ? i know its API 21...

Comment: Looks like this could be a solution in general, but I need this to work down to API 14...

Comment: ok but what about `File#canWrite()` ? you would need to convert your `Uri` to `File` though...

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know it's happened when you get the exception. *Why* it happened is another question. Android shouldn't allow it. I suspect you're writing to an invalid `pfd` object. Or else it's an Android bug.

Comment: @pskink: I don't think I can get a `File` from a `Uri` that starts with `content://` or am I missing something`?
@EJP: I want to know whether I can write to the file without modifying it. However, I only get the exception after trying to write to.

Comment: yep if it starts with `content://` you cannot do that...

Comment: BTW did you try to call `ContentResolver#openOutputStream(Uri uri)` directly and see if it returns null / throws an exception ?

Comment: @pskink: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it. I successfully get a non null `OutputStream` and the same exception when I try to write to it.

Comment: seems that i run out of ideas then...

Comment: last desperate idea: by accident i found two methods which i was not aware (thus never used them actually): `Context#checkCallingUriPermission (Uri uri, int modeFlags)` or `Context#checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission (Uri uri, int modeFlags)`

Comment: Interesting, this looked like a promising idea. In fact both of these functions return -1 (=`PERMISSION_DENIED`) when called with `modeFlages=Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` on the given `uri`. Unfortunately they also do so for uris/files to which I _can_ successfully write without the above exception appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are apparently two methods:

1. One can call

   ```
   Context.checkCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
   ```

   to check whether the calling process is allowed to write to a given `Uri`.

   For the cases I could check, on API level < 19 this seems to result in `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` whenever the writing to an output stream pointing to `uri` fails and in `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` in all other cases.

   For API level >= 19 it however yields `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` even if one has previously taken a persisted write permission with `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(Uri uri, int takeFlags)`. In that case however one can use

   ```
   context.getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions()
   ```

   to get a list of all previously taken permissions and then look through them so see if one has permission to write to a given `Uri`.
2. If one got he `Uri` via an `Intent intent` one can check its flags via `intent.getFlags()` and see whether `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` is set. This also seems to be a way to "predict the future".

Obviously, neither of the above methods can be an excuse to not properly handle exceptions that can occur while writing to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to test whether any resource is available is to try to use it, and handle the exceptions or errors that result when you can't.

Anything else amounts to fortune-telling. You might

- test the wrong thing
- test the right thing but get an answer that is correct for the time of the test but not for the time of the actual use. This can work two ways, both bad: the test says you can't, but later you could: or the test says you can, but later you can't.

Don't try to predict the future. Coping with the present is difficult enough.

Comment: What I am trying to do here is create an intuitive user interface. I think this is a perfectly legitimate reason for trying to predict the future. Of course exceptions then still need to be handled appropriately.

Comment: There can't possibly be a legitimate reason for trying to predict the future, for the simple reason that it can't be done.