# Android java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: java, android, file, encryption

I have read several posts about the EBADF error that does not resolve my issue. What makes my case unique is that I am trying to write to the getFilesDir, that should be writable by the application.

I am getting the EBADF error when executing the encrypt method. The file argument is created using:

```
new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "file.dat")
```

Where is a listing of the encrypt method:

```
public static void encrypt(File file, String password, List<Object> objects) {

    byte[] salt = generateSalt();
    byte[] iv = generateIV();
    Cipher c = createCipher(password, salt, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, iv);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        fos.write(salt);
        fos.write(iv);
        try (CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, c);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cos)) {
            for (Object o : objects) {
                oos.writeObject(o);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why I am getting the exception?

Here is the exception log:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.util.EncryptUtil.encrypt(EncryptUtil.java:69)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.store.Store.save(Store.java:94)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.store.Store.createSamples(Store.java:179)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.store.Store.load(Store.java:76)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.activity.login.LoginAction$2.doInBackground(LoginAction.java:62)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.activity.login.LoginAction$2.doInBackground(LoginAction.java:55)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:502)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
    at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.close(CipherOutputStream.java:129)
    at za.co.lot24media.password.util.EncryptUtil.encrypt(EncryptUtil.java:64)
```

** EDITED **

The issue seems to be with the ObjectOutputStream writing to the CipherOutputStream. When I remove the ObjectOutputStream from the encrypt() method, the method succeeds. The code below works:

```
    public static void encrypt(File file, String password, StoreDataRecord storeDataRecord) {

    byte[] salt = generateSalt();
    byte[] iv = generateIV();
    Cipher c = createCipher(password, salt, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, iv);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        fos.write(salt);
        fos.write(iv);

        try (CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, c)) {
            cos.write(new byte[10]);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I used byte[10] just to write arbitrary data to the stream.

** EDIT 2 **

The following solution also works, writing the data to a ByteArrayOutputStream first:

```
public static void encrypt(File file, String password, StoreDataRecord storeDataRecord) {

    byte[] salt = generateSalt();
    byte[] iv = generateIV();
    Cipher c = createCipher(password, salt, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, iv);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        fos.write(salt);
        fos.write(iv);

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
             CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, c)) {
            oos.writeObject(storeDataRecord.getVersion());
            oos.writeObject(storeDataRecord.getItems());
            cos.write(bos.toByteArray());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exception log

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the objects. Write the `List`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know whether writing to stream would result in java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089745/how-to-know-whether-writing-to-stream-would-result-in-java-io-ioexception-write)

Comment: it's not an exact duplicate, but the one duplicate (of many) which possibly helps the most.

Comment: The innermost try-with-resources is the `ObjectOutputStream`, which will be closed when the block exits, which will close the underlying streams and file, which will close the `FileOutputStream`, which will cause this exception when the `CipherOutputStream` is closedif it needs flushing, which it clearly does. Add `oos.flush()` after the (redundant) loop to ensure that the `CipherOutputStream` doesn't need flushing when it closes.

Comment: *should be writable by the application* Perhaps not.  Try adding debug code to explicitly check and show you what the permissions really are.  There's only one reason a [POSIX write() call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) will fail with `errno` set to `EBADF`:  "`EBADF`
    The `fildes` argument is not a valid file descriptor open for writing."  It's really hard with Java to get a completely invalid file descriptor - a value that doesn't even represent an open file at all.  So it's likely you don't have write permission on the file. Does it already exist?

Comment: The same EBADF exception is thrown when I add oos.flush() directly after oos.writeObject(o);

Comment: When I remove the CipherOutputStream from the encrypt, the method succeeds. This indicates that the destination file is writable.

Comment: at za.co.lot24media.password.util.EncryptUtil.encrypt(EncryptUtil.java:69) what is executed at line 69?

Comment: Hans, the encrypt method that i posted get executed.

Answer (score 0):

As i see your `encrypt` method call on `doInBackground` so it can produce some complicated situation like move to another fragment or create two instance of fragment and this make android confuse. Best way is you ignore `encrypt` method when `onDestroy()` called.

And make sure your streams not closed before you use them.

Hope it's helps